# Unable to resolve service for type '' while attempting to activate ''

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am creating a project on Core 2.0 and I have been stuck from last 2 days on dependency injection. Following is my code-

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddTransient<IAccountBAL, AccountBAL>();
}

public interface IAccountBAL
{
    Task CreateSuperAdmin();
}

public class AccountBAL:IAccountBAL
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _connection;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    public AccountBAL(ApplicationDbContext connection, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _connection = connection;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _userManager = userManager; 
    }
    public async Task CreateSuperAdmin()
    {
        //My Code  
    }
}
```

But when I run my project I am getting error **Unable to resolve service for type 'DALUser.Data.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'UserAuth.BAL.AccountBAL'**.
But when I remove IAccountBAL _iAccountBAL from  following code it works. B ut I need this dependency to be passed.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IAccountBAL _iAccountBAL)
{

}
```

Comment: There's a lot missing from your `ConfigureServices`. You're not registering your `ApplicationDbContext` (that's your actual error) but you're also missing registrations for `UserManager`, `RoleManager` and `SignInManager`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin You saved my rest times. Thank You. It was missing registration of UserManager, RoleManager and SignInManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Startup` class you need to register your `DbContext` like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ... 
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    });
    // ...
}
```

Here is the [example of registering custom `Identity` based `DbContext`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52347535/register-aspnetcore-2-1-identity-system-with-dbcontext-interface/52348144#52348144).

Comment: In my case it was missing registration of UserManager, RoleManager and SignInManager. Rest your answer is acceptable.

Comment: If you follow the approach the link I provided for to configure your own `Identity` based `DBContext` - you will have all needed registered right.