# Add Collection to user object in ASP.NET Core with Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I was playing around with EF Core and ASP.NET Core and stumbled into the following problem.
I wanted to add some extra data to the User Object in form of a List. The problem is that the List is never updated.

Here's my DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<HostUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

And now my User Object:

```
public class HostUser : IdentityUser
{
    [PersonalData]
    public ICollection<GuestUser> GuestUsers { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the adding of a new GuestUser in the Contoller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]GuestUser userToInsert)
    {
        if (userToInsert == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var currentUser = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
        if (currentUser == null)
        {
            return Forbid();
        }

        if(currentUser.GuestUsers?.Any(user => user.Id == userToInsert.Id) ?? false)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        if(currentUser.GuestUsers == null)
        {
            currentUser.GuestUsers = new List<GuestUser>();
        }

        currentUser.GuestUsers.Add(userToInsert);
        await userManager.UpdateAsync(currentUser);

        return Ok();
    }
```

My question is if this is a complete wrong approach and I have to add a DbSet of GuestUser in the DbContext and map it to the user.
If this is the case I have no idea how to achieve this.
Note: The GuestUser in this case is not another IdentityUser, it's local user data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how it might look like:

Entitties:

```
public class HostUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<GuestUser> GuestUsers { get; set; }
}

public class GuestUser
{
    public int HostUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual HostUser HostUser { get; set; }
}
```

DB Context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<HostUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<GuestUser> GuestUsers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<HostUser>(
            typeBuilder =>
            {
                typeBuilder.HasMany(host => host.GuestUsers)
                    .WithOne(guest => guest.HostUser)
                    .HasForeignKey(guest => guest.HostUserId)
                    .IsRequired();

                // ... other configuration is needed
            });

        builder.Entity<GuestUser>(
            typeBuilder =>
            {
                typeBuilder.HasOne(guest => guest.HostUser)
                    .WithMany(host => host.GuestUsers)
                    .HasForeignKey(guest => guest.HostUserId)
                    .IsRequired();

                // ... other configuration is needed
            });
    }
}
```

Controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] GuestUser userToInsert)
{
    // All checks and validation ...

    // You can get the current user ID from the user claim for instance
    int currentUserId = int.Parse(User.FindFirst(Claims.UserId).Value);

    // _context is your ApplicationDbContext injected via controller constructor DI 
    userToInsert.HostUserId = currentUserId;

    // Save new guest user associated with the current host user
    _context.GuestUsers.Add(userToInsert);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    // If you need to get the current user with all guests
    List<HostUser> currentUser = await _context.Users.Include(host => host.GuestUsers).ToListAsync();

    return Ok(currentUser);
}
```

Here I provided the full code - [how to configure custom Identity based DB context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52347535/register-aspnetcore-2-1-identity-system-with-dbcontext-interface/52348144#52348144) (all needed custom classed inherited from base classes used by `IdentityDbContext`).

Answer (score 2):

There are two issue.

1.First you should separate `ViewModel`from entity (don't pass `GuestUser` as your web/api method for parameter)

2.then as you mentioned you should declare a `DBSet` of `GuestUser` in `DbContext` and map it to the user table.

> **Define your Custom User Entity**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string CustomTag { get; set; }
}
```

> **Declare your Custom DbContext**
>
> Next use this type as a generic argument for the context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(b =>
        {
            // Each User can have many UserClaims
            b.HasMany(e => e.Claims)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UserId)
                .IsRequired();
        });
    }
}
```

> Update ConfigureServices to use the new ApplicationUser class:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

if you have any other problems let me know.

Comment: ok so I should create a DTO for the 'GuestUser' and instantiate the 'GuestUser' in the api method?
If you could give me an example of the mapping that would be nice, as I have zero experience with EF Core

Comment: yes this is it, I am preparing an example for you , and I will modify this answer 5 minutes later.

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand it. So **CustomTag** should be a **GuestUser** and **e.Claims** (in the **OnModelCreating** method) should be **e.GuestUser** in my case? I cannot see where the extra **DbSet<GuestUser>** should be mapped