# Can not set Id as primary key in ASP.NET Core code-first EF model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first

This is my model class:

```
public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<int>
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

The `Id` can not set the primary key and it creates extra columns `UserId1` and `RoleId1` in the database. What's the problem? How can I solve that?

Comment: Why do you need this properties again in your model class 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
?

Comment: @SonalBorkar i delete them but still `userid1` and `roleid1` is created

Comment: you may need to run update-database  from PM Console

Comment: i using that , but in database it created userid1 and roleid1

Comment: Run it again to remove the columns => update-database after deleting the properties from the model UserRole class

Comment: @SonalBorkar still have that problem

Comment: Check below => If you have the columns in your database migration file then you have to create the migration file again and run the update-database. Further, if there is no data in any tables in your database. then drop the database, delete migration code and create the migrations again and run update-database again

Comment: still have that problem

Comment: @kianoush show your User and Role model please! I am giving a solution to a solution.

Comment: You are inheriting your model from IdentityUserRole<int> class that already have userId and roleId property so there are two property in your model with same name. you should override the property like :   public override string UserId { get; set; }
    public override string RoleId { get; set; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for `UserRole` entity the key should be composite like this:

```
public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<int>
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

With configuration like:

```
userRole.HasKey(r => new
                        {
                            r.UserId,
                            r.RoleId
                        });
```

Here is the [example of configuring custom `IdentityDbContext`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52348144/804385) with all custom inherited entities including `IdentityUserRole`.

Comment: still have that problem

Comment: Make sure you dropped the previous migrations from your database

Answer (score 1):

As per the default convention, EF makes a property as foreign key property when its name matches with the primary key property of a related entity.
The [ForeignKey] attribute overrides the default convention for a foreign key It allows us to specify the foreign key property in the dependent entity whose name does not match with the primary key property of the principal entity.

Use Below code:-

```
public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<int>
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public override int RoleId { get; set; }
    public override int UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RoleId")] // Specify ForeignKey Column Name
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")] // Specify ForeignKey Column Name
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

OR You can use :-

```
public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<int>
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Role")] // Specify Table name on Property
        public override int RoleId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("User")] // Specify Table name on Property
        public override int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Entity Framework can by default map `Role` to `RoleId`. You don't need to mention explicitly if you follow the `EntityId` convention for foreign key.

Comment: override keyword before property is required.

Comment: it show me this error : `The relationship from 'UserRole.Role' to 'Role.Users' with foreign key properties {'RoleId' : int} cannot target the primary key {'Id' : int} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.
PM> `