# .NET Core 2.2 - Seed admin users

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a problem with my .NET Core 2.2 application. I added authentication and user entity to my application and now my application throws exceptions when started. When I am trying to add migrations another exception is throwed.

When I am trying to add initial migration:

> The seed entity for entity type 'AppUser' cannot be added because the
>   value provided for the property 'Id' is not of the type 'int'.
>   Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to
>   see the involved property values.

When I am trying to start my app:

> The seed entity for entity type 'AppUser' cannot be added because the
>   value '95ee39c2-a865-4272-8b67-da590fb4b80c' provided for the property
>   'Id' is not of the type 'int'.

I don't know what I did wrong. I tried to change this and that for couple of hours but without success.

**Startup.cs** -- ConfigureServices method

```
    services.AddDbContext<ResumeContext>(options => 
        options
            .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ResumeConnection"))
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
        );

    var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>(o =>
    {
        o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        o.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
        o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    });

    builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(AppRole), builder.Services);
    builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ResumeContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

**SeedData.cs**

```
public static class SeedData
{
    public static IWebHost SeedAdminUser(this IWebHost webHost)
    {
        using (var scope = webHost.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>();
            var roleManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<AppRole>>();

            if (userManager.Users.Any(u => u.Email == "admin@domain.com")) return webHost;

            roleManager.CreateAsync(new AppRole { Name = AppRole.Admin }).Wait();

            userManager.CreateAsync(new AppUser { UserName = "Admin", Email = "admin@domain.com" }, "CCZtE2XpqXbSs5B").Wait();

            userManager.AddToRoleAsync(userManager.FindByEmailAsync("admin@domain.com").Result, AppRole.Admin).Wait();
        }

        return webHost;
    }
}
```

**AppUser.cs**

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    // TODO: This will be extended in future
}
```

**User.cs**

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int AppUserId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public string PostalCode { get; set; } 

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ModifyDate { get; set; }

    public long? FacebookId { get; set; }

    public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
            .Build()
            .SeedAdminUser()
            .Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

**Context.cs**

```
public class ResumeContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, int>
{
    public ResumeContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Configure("Resume.Infrastructure.Data");
    }
}
```

Do anyone know what I am doing wrong? And how properly configure identity and seed admin user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `ResumeContext` is inherited from `IdentityDbContext` which uses `IdentityUser<int>`.

You can find the example how to configure custom `IdentityDbContext` with `int` based `IDs` here: [Your Identity based DB context should look like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52347535/register-aspnetcore-2-1-identity-system-with-dbcontext-interface/52348144#52348144)

Comment: I edited my post and added Context class. I believe that it's configured correct. Thank you for fast feedback :)

Comment: Your DB context class should look like public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin, RoleClaim, UserToken>    {  ... }  - full code is there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52347535/register-aspnetcore-2-1-identity-system-with-dbcontext-interface/52348144#52348144

Comment: Really? I need to create all those classes like UserClaim, RoleClaim and use inherit from: IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin, RoleClaim, UserToken>. It looks really, really strange :/

Comment: Well, all these classes are quite coupled. So it makes sense to define custom ones to get the full control on customizing logic around DB context. You can use base classes which come from standard namespaces where possible.