# How to Configure IdentityUserRole properly in DataContext Class using asp.net mvc core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-identity-3

I was created a IdentityUser table and IdentityRoleTable succefully and I can Insert it in both too.
even I was created a IdentityUserRole Tables Succefully too
but when I want to assign user to the roles that is previously defined it was occure:

*Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityUserRole' because this type is not included in the model for the context*

IdentityUserRole Code :

```
public class AppUserRole<T>:IdentityUserRole<string> 
{

    public virtual AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
    public virtual AppRole AppRole { get; set; }

}
```

DataContext Class:

```
public DbSet<AppUserRole<string>> AppUserRole { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) {
        builder.Entity<AppUserRole<string>>().HasKey(p => new { p.UserId, p.RoleId });
    }
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52347535/register-aspnetcore-2-1-identity-system-with-dbcontext-interface/52348144#52348144

Comment: oh yes . there is another way to conduct and so much complicated. but it worked