# Resolve DbContext by Interface in EFCore 3

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, dbcontext, ef-core-3.0

What's the correct way to register/resolve a DbContext by an Interface?

---

### Context:

I have multiple web services with a different dbcontext each.

Since I need to write some common functionalities in a shared project, I wrote an interface which is implemented by each dbcontext, so I can have the set of shared functionalities "dbcontext-implementation-agnostic" just injecting the dbcontext interface.

In each project, each dbcontext **is already used and injected by its implementation**, but I would like to use just its interface in the common features project.

So, in each webservice I would have something like:

```
services.AddDbContext<IMyDbcontext, MyDbcontext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbContext"));
});
services.AddTransient<ISharedService, SharedService>();
```

and in the shared project

```
public class SharedService : ISharedService
{
    public SharedService(IMydbcontext context)
    {
        [...]
    }

    [...]
}
```

having `IMyDbcontext` just like

```
public interface IMyDbcontext
{
    DbSet<SharedSettings> Settings { get; set; }

    int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
    int SaveChanges();
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}
```

and I require ISharedService within Startup.cs - Configure() with

```
app.ApplicationServices.GetService<ISharedService>();
```

---

I've been googling a lot and tried different approches but I couldn't find one which worked...

I've tried to use a forwarder, like this: (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52348155/1538384))

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>();
services.AddScoped<IMyDbContext>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>());
```

But, while I've no issues resolving the concrete `MyDbContext`, I get this error whenever I try to resolve `IMyDbContext`

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve
>   'Blah.IMyService' from root provider because it
>   requires scoped service
>   'Blah.IMydbcontext'.'

where `IMyService` is registered as transient and it's implementation constructor is

```
public MyService(IMydbcontext context)
```

---

I also tried to register the dbcontext like this

```
services.AddDbContext<IMyDbContext, MyDbContext>();
```

but then, when I try to resolve `MyDbContext` i get `null`, and I can't understand why

Comment: can you show a more detailed example of the current start up and also the relevant classes. It is unclear if you need to interface or the implementation.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to resolve both `MyDbContext` and `IMyDbContext` you'll have to register both types. `AddDbContext<IMyDbContext, MyDbContext>` only registers `IMyDbContext` with an implementation provided by `MyDbContext`. Simply registering `MyDbContext` is enough though - any code that expects a `MyDbContext` will get one and never have to know where the data came from, eg database or dictionary.

Comment: i've added more context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [/u/AngularBeginner](https://www.reddit.com/user/AngularBeginner):

> The `IMyService` requires a scoped `IMyDbContext`, but within your
>   startups Configure() method you don't have a scope.
>
> You can make your `IDbContext` transient (if that's acceptable to
>   you).
>
> Alternatively you can try to create a temporary scope using the
>   `CreateScope()` method, then get your IMyService from that new scoped
>   provider.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/e6xs4q/resolve_dbcontext_by_interface_in_efcore_3/f9tr30c/)

So, I created a scope with IServiceScopeFactory and it did the trick

```
var scopeFactory = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();   
using var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope();
var myService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMyService>();
```